# Navigate to a particular tab(used dojo tabcontainer) in a page from hyperlink in another html

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, dojo, tabcontainer

I have a html page. In that page there is one link. After clicking on that link I want to to navigate to a completely new page which has many tabs. I have created these tabs using dojo tabcontainer. Now the problem is that, i can navigate to the new page containing these tabs and by default the first tab opens up. But i want to dynamically change the tab which should open up when i navigate to this page. Suppose that clicking on a link in first html page should navigate to the page containing tabs and opens 3rd tab. Similarly in some conditions it should open any other tab. And choosing tabs is done in the first page which is again dynamic. How to achieve this ?

```
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" id="tabcontainerId" style="height:100%">
            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane"  region="center" title="Title1">
                <div dojoAttachPoint="title1WidgetHolder" id="title1WidgetHolder"></div>
            </div>
            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane"  region="center" title="Title2" id="title2PaneId">
                <div dojoAttachPoint="title2WidgetHolder" id="title2WidgetHolder"></div>
            </div>
            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane"  region="center" title="Title3" id="title3PaneId">
                <div dojoAttachPoint="title3WidgetHolder" id="title3WidgetHolder"</div>
            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane"  region="center" id="title4PaneId" title="Title4">

            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the tabs page where I want to come after navigation. First page will have a link, clicking on which i will come to this tabs page.

Hope this question is clear.

PS: I donot want to first come to this page and change the tabs in ready() or dojo.addOnload(), which can be done using selectChild()

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your page is processed on the server (with php for instance) you can generate the HTML according to the tab you want to load at first. If this is a plain html page then you will have to use `ready()`

Answer (score 0):

Different HTML pages do not share an application state, which is what you need to open a specific tab.

The Tabcontainer has a specific DOM attribute to allow you to open a specific tab in a declarative way: 'selected'. If its value is true, then the widget will open that ContentPane.

You are most likely using parseOnLoad: true here, so I'd suggest the following:
Add a URL parameter to the URL with the desired TabId by means of a hash parameter, and in the new page extract that parameter from the URL.
Then before you parse the DOM and bring up all the widgets, add the selected attribute to that specific contentPane.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/layout/TabContainer.html describes the selected attribute.

Alternatively, you could use the selectChild API in a similar way, if you do not want to change DOM attributes.

One thing is for sure though: You must persist the information of which tab you'd like to open, either via a URL parameter, or by means of an API, or by means of a cookie/localStorage.